# Finality in Casper: can full node delete everything other than block header and state tree after reaching finality?

Tags: go-ethereum, consensus, ethcore

In the coming release Casper, I am assuming after Casper reaches finality, the finalized block will never reorg. Is it safe for the full nodes to delete everything (e.g., all transactions) other than block header and state tree before than block?

A new full block can recover without all transactions by:

1. Replay the block headers till the last finalized block, to get the latest state merkle root.
2. Asks for a full copy of the state tree, verify with the merkle root.
3. Continue normally

Comment: No, there's no finality in Ethereum. Given enough hashing power someone could mine a new version of the main canonical chain. It's eventually consistent, but not final.

Comment: @RichardHorrocks Sorry, I should have stated, I meant Ethereum Casper, the coming release.

Comment: Okay, understood. Might be worth modifying the question (including the title) to make this clear :-)

Answer (score 0):

> I am assuming after Casper reaches finality, the finalized block will never reorg.

Finality is not 100% guaranteed as there will always be a non-zero probability of a double-finality; hence why slashing conditions exist to punish such occurrences.

In practice, it is believed that the probability of a reorg will be very low due to economic disincentives, but it cannot be quantified precisely so it is a subjective decision whether your suggestion is "safe" in practice.